# How to render form.errors without html tag

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

i want to render form.errors individually without the html tag but it doesn't seem to work

views.py

```py
....
context = {
        'login_error': form.errors,
        'login_form': LoginForm(),
    }

return render(request, 'shop/login.html', context)
....
```

login.html

```html
....
<label class="mt-1"> {{ login_form.username.label }} </label>
{{ login_form.username }}
{{ login_error.username }}

<label class="mt-1"> {{ login_form.password.label }} </label>
{{ login_form.password }}
{{ login_error.password }}
....
```

the answer i got is by unpacking it in a loop and then add an `|escape`

```html
....
{% for error in login_error %}
{{ error|escape }}
{% endfor %}

<label class="mt-1"> {{ login_form.username.label }} </label>
{{ login_form.username }}

<label class="mt-1"> {{ login_form.password.label }} </label>
{{ login_form.password }}
....
```

so, the question is, why does this output with html tag

```html
{{ login_error.username|escape }}
{{ login_error.password|escape }}
```

but this one output without html tag which is basically the same (?) as the above

```html
{% for error in login_error %}
{{ error|escape }}
{% endfor %}
```

**the expected outcome is the field error without html tag, but `{{ login_error.username|escape }}` also outputs the html tag**

```html
{% for error in login_error %}
{{ error|escape }}
{% endfor %}
```

outputs with no html tag but a loop is needed, i need to output errors individually but without the html tag

Comment: Plz add error details u come across for {{ login_error.username|escape }}, in order to debug efficiently!

Comment: @AbijithMg there is no error, the ```|escape``` just doesnt work for ```{{ login_error.username|escape }}```